# Streamlining button creation and Handlers

Tags: beginner, vb.net

The code below works but I can not help thinking it's to 'clunky' and could be so much tidier! It's the first time I've really used AddHandler so go gentle...

Create button(s) and handler(s)

```
The code below works but I can not help thinking it's to 'clunky' and could be so much tidier! It's the first time I've really used AddHandler so go gentle...
```

Create button(s) and handler(s)

```
 Public Sub AddChartRow(ByVal button As String, ByVal id As String, ByVal high As Integer, ByVal medium As Integer, ByVal low As Integer, ByVal na As Integer)

    ChartArea.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(" <div Class=""bar-row"">"))

    Dim btnButton As New Button() With {.Text = button, .ID = id, .CssClass = vRiskActive}

            If id = "btn1" Then
                AddHandler btnButton.Click, AddressOf btnItem_1 ' here Buttons is your Handler  
            End If
            If id = "btn2" Then
                AddHandler btnButton.Click, AddressOf btnItem_2 ' here Buttons is your Handler  
            End If
            If id = "btn3" Then
                AddHandler btnButton.Click, AddressOf btnItem_3 ' here Buttons is your Handler  
            End If
If id = "btn4" Then
                AddHandler btnButton.Click, AddressOf btnItem_4 ' here Buttons is your Handler  
            End If
If id = "btn5" Then
                AddHandler btnButton.Click, AddressOf btnItem_5 ' here Buttons is your Handler  
            End If
If id = "btn6" Then
                AddHandler btnButton.Click, AddressOf btnItem_6 ' here Buttons is your Handler  
            End If
If id = "btn7" Then
                AddHandler btnButton.Click, AddressOf btnItem_7 ' here Buttons is your Handler  
            End If
If id = "btn8" Then
                AddHandler btnButton.Click, AddressOf btnItem_8 ' here Buttons is your Handler  
            End If

If id = "btn9" Then
                AddHandler btnButton.Click, AddressOf btnItem_9 ' here Buttons is your Handler  
            End If
If id = "btn10" Then
                AddHandler btnButton.Click, AddressOf btnItem_10 ' here Buttons is your Handler  
            End If

            If (oGetPercentages.SumTotal) <> "0" Then
                ChartArea.Controls.Add(btnButton)
                ChartArea.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("  <div Class=""bar-data"">" & "      <div Class=""bar-inner"">" & " <div Class=""bar bar-high"" style=""width:  " & (oGetPercentages.HighPer) & "%"">" & high & "</div>" & "          <div class=""bar bar-med"" style=""width: " & (oGetPercentages.MedPer) & "%"">" & medium & "</div>" & "  <div class=""bar bar-low"" style=""width: " & (oGetPercentages.LowPer) & "%"">" & low & "</div>" & "          <div class=""bar bar-na"" style=""width: " & (oGetPercentages.NAPer) & "%"">" & na & "</div>" & "      </div>" & "  </div>" & "</div>"))
            Else
                ChartAreaGrey.Controls.Add(btnButton)
                ChartAreaGrey.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("  <div class=""bar-data"">" & "      <div class=""bar-inner bar-inactive"">" & "  </div>" & "  </div>" & "</div>"))
            End If

        End Sub



 Public Sub btnItem_1()
            Call PrcDash2("1")
        End Sub

        Public Sub btnItem_2()
            Call PrcDash2("2")
        End Sub

        Public Sub btnItem_3()
            Call PrcDash2("3")
        End Sub 

 Public Sub btnItem_4()
            Call PrcDash2("4")
        End Sub

 Public Sub btnItem_5()
            Call PrcDash2("5")
        End Sub

 Public Sub btnItem_6()
            Call PrcDash2("6")
        End Sub

 Public Sub btnItem_7()
            Call PrcDash2("7")
        End Sub

 Public Sub btnItem_8()
            Call PrcDash2("8")
        End Sub

 Public Sub btnItem_9()
            Call PrcDash2("9")
        End Sub

 Public Sub btnItem_10()
            Call PrcDash2("10")
        End Sub
```

Comment: How many are there in your original (you say you have limited to 3)

Comment: 10 at the moment. It's runs fine but just looks like it could be smaller!

Comment: 10 isn't that bad, you should add them all in your question even although the question will be longer

Comment: Like, for instance, is it all `PrcDash2`?

Comment: Yes, all goes the same place, just need to know the button that's pressed for a different variable.

Comment: Mind adding the rest of the cases, then?

Comment: Done, but it may go up/down in the future of course

Comment: are you sure you did it correctly? There's bugs in the code right now with the handler for button 4

Comment: Fixed, changed the names to 1 to 10 for logic and missed the 4th one. Yes it works perfectly but I've iterated the names and taken out items not related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Button` control/class has a `Tag` property of type `Object`. You could simply pass to that property your strings "1", "2" etc. In this way you would only need one eventhandler where you the read the value of the `Tag` property back, call the `ToString()` method and then pass this string as argument to the `PrcDash2()` method.

Comment: Go on then might Friday after work brain but remind me (please). Always obvious after!

Answer (score 0):

Better solution (based on what Heslacher said)

'Set Handler as buttons are created and use button ID to work out which is pressed

```
AddHandler btnButton.Click, AddressOf btnGroupSend
```

Which sets up a handler then in the aspx.vb code:

```
Public Sub btnGroupSend(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)    

         Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Response.Redirect("dashboard3.aspx?a=" & Functions.fncButtonValue(btn.ID))

    End Sub
```

Calling:

```
Public Shared Function fncButtonValue(vID As String) As String


        If vID = "btnxyz Then vID = "1"
        If vID = "btnExample" Then vID = "2" 

        Return vID

    End Function
```